# Web application with map containing tabular data and wiki-style editable pages

Tags: web-apps, maps, self-hosted, wiki

My geologist colleagues are asking for a self-hosted website with the following features:

- A map with points for them to create and attach measurements to. Points should be grouped/filtered by expedition and kind of measurement. Clicking on a point on the map should result in a pop-up containing the measurements for the point.
- A tabular interface to edit existing points or measurements and enter new points or measurements. Placing points on the map by pointing an clicking is not at all important; the coordinates are expected to be copied & pasted from a lab journal together with the measurement results.
- Wiki-style editable pages with file attachments for each expedition.

The number of expeditions is less than 10 per year; the number of points in an expedition is up to a few 100s; the number of kinds of measurements is up to a few 10s. The dataset is expected to be sparse: not all kinds of measurements are performed on all samples, and most expeditions sample at different coordinates.

[Semantic MediaWiki with the Maps extension](https://maps.extension.wiki/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki) almost does what we need, except I don't know how to fulfil the second requirement. As far as I understand Semantic MediaWiki, it's possible to construct very elaborate queries and place their results on the map [with pop-ups subject to a template I could create](https://maps.extension.wiki/wiki/Leaflet_SMW_queries), but I'd have to create a wiki page per sampling point, because I can't set multiple properties of the same type in a page.

Any other MediaWiki extensions I'm overlooking? Any other way I could achieve the desired result?

This feels deceptively simple enough that one could probably code an approximation of the desired feature set by themselves, but safely accepting user-generated content (especially pages and file attachments) could be annoying to get right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we went with Semantic MediaWiki + Maps + Semantic Forms + Semantic Scribunto, creating one wiki page per sampling point.

The expedition pages are all generated from a template, making it easy to list the existing sampling points with `{{Special:PrefixIndex/{{FULLPAGENAME}}/ |hideredirects=1 |stripprefix=1}}` and create a new sampling point with `{{#forminput:form=SamplingPoint|super_page={{FULLPAGENAME}}}}`, and the sampling point pages make use of Semantic Forms to allow editing all kinds of measurements using `[[Special:FormEdit/SamplingPoint/{{FULLPAGENAME}}|Edit measurements for this sampling point]]`.

The worst part was having to write a Lua module in Semantic Scribunto to (1) query for all kinds of measurements, (2) group them by sampling point (have I missed a `GROUP BY` in Semantic MediaWiki?) and (3) generate wiki markup to display a map of those. Basically, it's

```
function(frame)
 local sampling_points = mw.smw.getQueryResult(...)
 return frame:preprocess('<display_map service="leaflet" height="...">\n' ..
  table.concat(map(sampling_points, format_sampling_point), '\n') ..
  '</display_map>'
 )
```

combined with `format_sampling_point` generating the `Location~Popup title~Popup text~File:CustomIcon` markup for the Maps extension to render. The Popup text includes some `<table>`s to summarise the information. It's almost surprising that it still works.

A custom web application is still in the early stage of development and may be not completed at all, so the 80/20 rule wins again.